# How to extract multiple URL from string

Tags: javascript

I have string like this - `"https://gaana.com/song/dil-chahte-hohttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APmhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APm"`

In here I have three urls, how can i separate them and push them into an array. the url's can be start with http or https or directly from www or any valid url. I want the output like -

```
[
"https://gaana.com/song/dil-chahte-ho",
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APm",
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APm"
]
```

Comment: Yikes!  Unfortunately, that string is ambiguous.  URLs can contain `https://` *within them*, so it isn't going to be possible for you to separate them unless you know something about the URLs.  For example, if you're always dealing with YouTube, this isn't going to be a problem.  But if you have to handle arbitrary URLs, this isn't going to work reliably.  Where are you getting the string from?  Can you change it?

Comment: i am getting this string from textarea value. Form the value I want to extract the urls only.

Comment: like this - 

urlChecker(value : string){
  let textValue = value.replace(/\s{2,}/g, '');
  let urls : Array<any> = [];

  let urlRegex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?([^ ])+");

  if (textValue != '' && urlRegex.test(textValue)){
    let matchedIfUrl = urlRegex.exec(textValue);
    if(matchedIfUrl != null && matchedIfUrl != undefined){
      textWithUrl = matchedIfUrl[0];
      console.log(textWithUrl);
    }
  }
}

Comment: Are you sure these aren't coming in as separate lines?  Not sure why someone would paste this.

Comment: yah there were new lines in the textarea value I have removed the newlines from the textarea value with this - let textValue = value.replace(/\s{2,}/g, '');

Comment: @RAHULKUNDU The right solution is to redesign the source of generating these URLs to get them separately.

Comment: @RAHULKUNDU Why have you removed the newline characters?  You could just split on newline.

Comment: Hey, @Brad do not blame me, I am not the one posting the question. :)

Comment: @Rman Sorry Rman, meant to tag RAHUL.  :-)

Comment: @Brad - how can split the new lines?

Comment: @RAHULKUNDU `document.querySelector('textarea').value.split('\n')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var t = "https://gaana.com/song/dil-chahte-hohttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APmhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APm"
t = t.split("http").map(x => { return "http"+x }).slice(1)
```

First split the string on "http", which gives you an array. Then append the http to each element of the string. Unfortunately you end up with the first element in the array being "http" that's why you need to slice to remove it.

Comment: with http can i check www in here, like if any starts with only www. because I am getting that from textarea value and i have removed new lines from the value and sting the string is var t

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following code in Python:

```py
links_str = "https://gaana.com/song/dil-chahte-hohttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APmhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APm"

links = ["http"+str(link) for link in links_str.split("http")][1:]
```

Maybe you can try to do something like this in JavaSript.

Comment: This is a JavaScript question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var urls = "https://gaana.com/song/dil-chahte-hohttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APmhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APm"
urls = urls.split("https://").map(val => { return "https://"+val }).slice(1)
console.log(urls);
```

try this one it will help to split https value in the string

Answer (score 0):

```
const string = "https://gaana.com/song/dil-chahte-hohttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APmhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APm"
const http = string.split("http://").map(val => { return "http://"+val }).slice(1)
const https = string.split("https://").map(val => { return "https://"+val }).slice(1)
const array = [...http, ...https]
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way add to space or other delimiter before http and split string:

```
const str = "https://gaana.com/song/dil-chahte-hohttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APmhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APm";
const result = str.replace(/http/g, ' $&').split(' ');
// result ["", "https://gaana.com/song/dil-chahte-ho", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APm", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWnFCGXjjS0&list=PLs1-UdHIwbo5p-8wh740E7CRhIoKq5APm"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I had to convert a String with multiple URLS to an Array. So I used a regex to handle the urls and .match() method for creating an Array.

```
let urls = '[https://website.com/slug, https://website.com/other-slug]';

function convertUrlStringToArray(urls) {
    let expression = /\b(https?:\/\/\S*\b)/g;
    let regex = new RegExp(expression);

    return urls.match(regex);
}
```

Output an Array:
`[ 'https://website.com/slug', 'https://website.com/other-slug' ]`